# How to rename a file in WIndows that contains a wildcard in the filename

Tags: cmd, rename, wildcard, filenames

A friend gave me some files on a USB drive that was formatted as NTFS.  From his **Linux** system he copied a file containing a ? (e.g. "Which way to Millinocket?.mp3").  I can not copy that file using my Windows 10 system.  Not from Windows Explorer nor from the cmd prompt.  I get an error *The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*.  Del, ren, copy all fail.  Dir will show the files, and accepts the actual filename.

```
>ren "Which Way to Millinocket?.mp3" foo.mp3
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I am looking for a Windows solution.  Yes I can bring the drive back to my friend.  No I do not have my own Linux system.  Is there a way to escape the ? such that I can rename the file?

Comment: In searching for an answer I found that Linux apparently allows most characters in filenames.  You can put asterisk, question mark, single quote, double quote, etc...  In all my years I've never come across that.  Most have been spent in Windows, before that CP/M and DOS, so I guess they are all the same family.  My small exposure to Unix never used these characters in filenames.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem using a bootable USB drive and found no solution to access the file from within Windows 10. An alternative could be if you have a network device which allows to attach an USB drive (NAS, Router or Network media player). These usually use Unix operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Windows, display the file in Explorer.
2. Click on the file name.
3. Press the <kbd>F2</kbd> key, and rename the file.
4. Now go ahead and copy it.

Comment: As I said, Windows Explorer errors out on rename or copy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the short 8.3 filename which every file under windows still has for compatibility reasons.
List the files using `dir /x`. The list will contain the 8.3 filenames with tilde (~) symbol in the name. You should be able to rename the file using the rename command and giving the 8.3 filename as old filename:

```
ren "8.3 filename" "some new filename"
```

Comment: Good idea.  This was one of my first thoughts on how to work around this.  Unfortunately there is no short filename.  Dir /X shows nothing for the short name.  Sorry, I forgot to mention this in the original post.

Comment: Oh. It seems, your friends Unix system writes incompatible NTFS file entries! This is not nice. Even if you have no Unix system at hand, you could still use a bootable Linux image on an USB drive. There are plenty of those availabe from the internet.

Comment: Good idea.  Didn't think of that.